# variable text contains multiple patterns

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, purrr, stringr

I need to know if the `match` variable is contained in the `url` variable:

```
df1 = data.frame(match  = c("2234436803329252","460696711422302"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 = data.frame(url = c("https://business.facebook.com/460696711422302/", "https://twitter.com/status/1192745040302477312"),stringsAsFactors = F)

df1 %>% mutate(is_in_url = str_detect(df1$match,fixed(df2$url,ignore_case = T )
```

It returns a vector `c(FALSE, FALSE)`, but "*https://business.facebook.com/460696711422302/*" contains "*460696711422302*". Are there resources with `dplyr` and `stringr` libraries?

Comment: `str_detect(df2$url, paste(df1$match, collapse="|"))`

Comment: Be careful with false positives (partial matching) if you have short strings to match. To take an extreme example, if you end up with `"2"` in `match`, you'll inadvertently select any url containing `"2"`. If you can make assumptions about the strings to match (always numeric?) and/or about the URL format, you may be better off extracting potential ids from the url and match on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `grepl()` in `base R` can reach. You can have a try with

```
> with(df2,grepl(with(df1,paste0(match,collapse = "|")),url))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

- Or using `match()` and `Map()`

```
> Map(function(s) ifelse(any(!is.na(match(df1$match,unlist(regmatches(s,regexpr("\\d+",s)))))),T,F),df2$url)
$`https://business.facebook.com/460696711422302/`
[1] TRUE

$`https://twitter.com/status/1192745040302477312`
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I have a large dataframe. I exceed the number of characters in the regular expression

Comment: How about `apply(df2,1,function(s) any(match(df1$match,unlist(regmatches(s,regexpr("\\d+",s))))))`? @MarioM.

Comment: I also added a solution by using `match()` and `Map()`, so please check it out if they can work@MarioM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `string_detect` checks for a match only component wise.
Consider this simple example:

```
> str_detect(c("a", "b"), c("b", "a"))
[1] FALSE FALSE
> str_detect(c("a", "b"), c("a", "b"))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

So the first component of the string is only checked for the first component of the pattern. This is why in your case you have `c(FALSE, FALSE)` as a result.

You could try this instead:

```
match <- c("2234436803329252","460696711422302")
url <- c("https://business.facebook.com/460696711422302/", "https://twitter.com/status/1192745040302477312")

sapply(url, function(x) any(str_detect(x, match)))
https://business.facebook.com/460696711422302/ https://twitter.com/status/1192745040302477312 
                                          TRUE                                          FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sapply is a very very slow function :( I have a large dataframe!